# Matching a Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, sql

This may seem like an obvious thing, but I want to know know if there are wildcards in C# for matching strings.
I want to write a program so that users can search for something based on the date value in the database. What I have so far works as long as the whole date is entered, but entering half a date causes a parsing error
I'm using this code now

```
" ... where Date like " DateTime.Parse(textbox.text.trim()) " + %;"
```

I want to see if there is an way to see what the user input (only the year, or month and year without day,  or for it not to crash if only half the year is entered)

A solution that involves doing this in SQL itself doesn't matter

Comment: Sounds like you parse the user input to match with the db date value. You could instead stringify the db date value to check if it contains the raw user input, so no parsing errors will occur. For actual pattern-matching needs see the `Regex` class

Comment: I would prefer it if no JavaScript is involved, as I also want to learn the C# wildcards, but I can't find anywhere showing the C# wilcards

Comment: Regex != javascript

Comment: I was talking only about stringify, which I think is something with `JSON`

Comment: Currently I'm trying to see if regex will work for me

Comment: In C# you have not wildcard.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show an example of using `Regex`

Comment: Use `DateTimePicker` instead of `TextBox` for user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
public static class MyStringExtensions
{
  public static bool Like(this string toSearch, string toFind)
  {
   return new Regex(@"\A" + new Regex(@"\.|\$|\^|\{|\[|\(|\||\)|\*|\+|\?|\\").Replace(toFind, ch => @"\" + ch).Replace('_', '.').Replace("%", ".*") +  @"\z", RegexOptions.Singleline).IsMatch(toSearch);
  }
}

examples:
bool willBeTrue = "abcdefg".Like("abcd_fg");
bool willAlsoBeTrue = "abcdefg".Like("ab%f%");
bool willBeFalse = "abcdefghi".Like("abcd_fg");
```

Solution2:

```
madate.ToString().Contain("myvalue")
madate.ToString().StartWith("myvalue")
madate.ToString().EndWith("myvalue")
```

or use sql :
       where CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),yourdate, 103) like '%yourvalue%'

Comment: I meant in this question. Correct input format will be `dd/MM/yyyy`, but may be `MM/yyyy` if exact date is unknown

Comment: Build you SQL like this, select * from yourtable where cast(yourdate as varchar(50)) like '%yourvalue%'

Comment: will it change `dd/MM/yyyy` to `MMM dd yyyy`

Comment: What database are you? You will always cast a date into char and do a like, i dont anderstand, sorry my English is not really good. In SQL Server you can use Convert function, in DB2 VARCHAR_FORMAT(MYDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')

Comment: I'm using SQL server, its just that I'm new.

Comment: It worked. Add this to your answer and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

```
   where CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),yourdate, 103) like '%yourvalue%'
```